# Heatplot empty with R

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, spatial

I am trying to create a heatplot from a dataframe with coordinates of points and temperature data. Here a subset of the data:

```
my_df <- data.frame(
  Device = c("574fd825515802e0", "954fd825515802e0", "8d50d825515802e0", "814fd825515802e0", "2f4ed825515802e0", "354fd825515802e0", "8e4fd825515802e0", "304fd825515802e0", "644fd825515802e0", "2c4fd825515802e0", "5d4fd825515802e0"),
  temperature = c(30.5, 30.4, 30.4, 30.4, 30.5, 30.4, 30.5, 21.3, 21.0, 22.1, 22.9),
  latitude = c(51.00690, 51.05912, 51.05697, 51.05623, 51.05424, 51.07791, 51.04715, 51.02764, 51.02775, 51.02819, 51.03323),
  longitude = c(13.79522, 13.77990, 13.77771, 13.78579, 13.78142, 13.74717, 13.75613, 13.71432, 13.71461, 13.71190, 13.71724)
)
```

I want to create something similar to this, based on the temperature values:
[image]

i was able to create the background from google maps (using an API-key) and the points using geom_point but the problem is the heatmap, I thought geom_tile would be a good option but when i create the plot is not shown anywhere:

```
register_google(key = "here my API key")

# Retrieve the map background
map <- get_googlemap(center = c(lon = mean(my_df$longitude), lat = mean(my_df$latitude)), zoom = 11, scale = 2)

# Convert the map to a ggmap object
map_ggmap <- ggmap(map)

# Create the point layer for geographical points
points <- geom_point(data = my_df, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude), color = "black", size = 2)

# Create heatmap:
heat =  geom_tile(data = my_df, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, fill=temperature), interpolate = TRUE)

# Combine the map, heatmap, and point layers
heatmap_with_map <- map_ggmap + points + heat

heatmap_with_map
```

[image]

I thought a layer could be covering the heatmap so i tried to plot only it and nothing else but i become a blank image. I also tried to use geom_raster but i got error because points are not even distributed.
So please tell me what is wrong or what would be a better function to use to create the heatmap

Comment: The issue with `geom_tile` is that in case of a continuous scale the size of the tiles is squished down to zero. To make them visible you could e.g. try with `geom_tile(..., height = .01, width = .01)`. Also note that there is a typo in your code, both longitude and latitude missed the `e` at the end. Moreover, the kind of plot you are trying to replicate is a contour plot, i.e. have a look a `geom_contour_filled`. But I'm afraid your data isn't sufficient to create a contour plot.

Comment: the typo was by copying here the data, i edited it, but that is not the problem. Using the height and width parameters i get big squares instead of points but no heatmap. My real dataset has 97 rows, how can i use geom_contour_filled in this case?